# How can I send URL parameter in ASP.NET Core Web API parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I wrote this code in a C# ASP.NET Core Web API project:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetShortURL/{_url}/{tokenPass}")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "ShortURL")]
public ActionResult<ServiceResult<string>> GetShortURL(string _url, string tokenPass)
```

When I enter this parameter as `_url`, I get an error:

> Error: Not Found

> https://github.com/VahidN/DNTPersianUtils.Core

```
http://...//GetShortURL/https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FVahidN%2FDNTPersianUtils.Core/TokenPass
```

How can I call this API with the first Web URL parameter?
when i change the [Route("GetShortURL/{_url}/{tokenPass}")] to [Route("GetShortURL")] the problem was solved but i want to send query by / not by ?
for example, i want to call API like this :

> 1- http://..../GetShortURL/_UrlParam/_TokenPassParam

not like below :

> 2-  http://..../GetShortURL?_url=_urlParam&tokenPass=_TokenPassParam

the second way works fine but I want first way to work correctly when i pass an URL  like this

> https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FVahidN%2FDNTPersianUtils.Core

can anyone help me?

Comment: Sorry, what error are you getting?

Comment: Error: Not Found

Comment: Is there any route prefix?

Comment: no , i define it in attribute ... [Route("GetShortURL/{_url}/{tokenPass}")]

Comment: i can call below address

Comment: localhost:52213/GetShortURL/eeeeee/tokenpass

Comment: but when i call localhost:52213/GetShortURL/https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F16265653%2Fspecify-default-controller-action-route-in-webapi-using-attributerouting/tokenpass then i hit the wall and message me that not found error 404

Comment: Could you try passing these values as query parameters? Refer [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29243198/13584363)

Comment: when i use this attribute : [Route("/GetShortURL")] """ Every thing work OK but when define Parameter in this Attribute like this : [Route("/GetShortURL/{_url}/{tokenPass}")] , i cant call this WebApi by URL Value

Comment: this link work fine: http://localhost:52213/GetShortURL?_url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FVahidN%2FDNTPersianUtils.Core&tokenPass=TokenPass

Comment: but i want to separate parameters by /

Comment: Please edit the question to add any extra detail/clarity rather than in the comments.

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavifar is there a reason why you want the "/" (path parameter) way and not the query parameter way?

Comment: @AnindyaDey to Make it easier to call this API without writing parameter name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First approach:**
Pass the params you want as *query string* and then change the method like below:

```
[HttpGet("GetShortURL")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "ShortURL")]
public ActionResult<ServiceResult<string>> GetShortURL(string _url, string tokenPass)
```

Then For extracting the different parts of the url *(protocol, domain name, path and query string)*, use the code below (path is an array separated by slash):

```
try
{
    var decodedUrl = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(_url);
    Uri uri = new Uri(decodedUrl);    
    var scheme = uri.Scheme;            
    var host = uri.Host;
    var absolutePathSeperatedBySlash = uri.AbsolutePath.Split('/').Skip(1).ToList();
    var query = uri.Query;
    // rest of the code ...
     
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //...
}
```

**Second approach:**

If you want it to be sent as a url parameter, first you have to encode the value of `_url` with `encodeURIComponent()` in javascript, to make sure that some special characters like `, / ? : @ & = + $ #` are changed.

Then:

```
[HttpGet("GetShortURL/{_url}/{tokenPass}")]
[ApiExplorerSettings(GroupName = "ShortURL")]
public ActionResult<ServiceResult<string>> GetShortURL(string _url, string tokenPass)
```

The rest is just like the method body of the first approach.

Comment: thank you - I think that I can't say my question correctly--- so I edit that

Comment: I edited the answer based on what you asked, hope it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

With the following url

```
http://...//GetShortURL/https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FVahidN%2FDNTPersianUtils.Core/TokenPass
```

The value of _url will be:
[image]

If you want to convert it to a correct url,you needs to replace `%2F` with `/` in `GetShortURL`:

```
var url = _url.Replace("%2F","/");
```

Comment: thank you but this is not the answer of my question...

Comment: You can use the second way to pass url and replace `%2F` with `/`.

Comment: this URL https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FVahidN%2FDNTPersianUtils.Core automatically converted to https://github.com/FVahidN/FDNTPersianUtils.Core and i don't need to use replace method .. . my question is that when I use the first way this can not call my API

Answer (score 0):

just make parameters to be optional

```
[HttpGet("GetShortURL/{_url?}/{tokenPass?}")]
public ActionResult<ServiceResult<string>> GetShortURL(string _url, string tokenPass)
```

in this case you can call the action without any parameters, with one parameter or with two parameters